# How can I Add a number to each div id created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am using a django for loop to pull information from a query set. Also, as it prints the information, I want it to do so with a surrounding div tag who's id increments by 1 for each instance. How do I go about this? is it possible in django or do I need javascript? if so, how?
view:

```
 for x in y:

   Print(x)
```

I would like to get back:
template:

```
 {%for x in y%}
      {{x}}

 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="col">collapse</button>
 {%endfor%}
```

but all of my IDs come out as:

```
   <div id="col">x1</div>
   <div id="col">x2</div>
   <div id="col">x3</div>
```

If all the divs have the same ID then they will collapse and open at the same time, i want that to happen individually

Comment: Question seems unclear.. what's your current div structure..? and what is the required div structure..?

Comment: Are your divs being created dynamically?

Comment: yes they are being created dynamically, with and ID of item and class  of collapse. I want it to come out with an ID of item1 and and increment for each div created. The reason is so that I can apply bootstraps collapse feature to them without closing and opening all of them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{% for x in y %}
  {{ x }}
  {{ forloop.counter }} #prints the number


#if y = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
#{{ forloop.counter }} will print 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: YES!!! exactly this, you have no idea how long I've been looking for this. Thank you so much